# Another non-regular C-M ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

Among other examples of Cohen-macaulay rings which are not regular I am run into $R=F[x]/(x^2)$ with $F$ a field. It is clear that it is not regular, since every regular local ring must be a domain while $x+(x^2)$ is a zero-divisor. My question is that why $R$ is a local Artinian ring? My try is that $(x)+(x^2)$ is a maximal ideal of $R$. I am aware also of the fact that each Artinian ring is Cohen-Macaulay. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, so any ideal above $(x^2)$ must be generated by a divisor of $x^2$. From this you should see the ring has exactly three ideals.

This should also prime you to see why $F[x]/(x^n)$ is local for any positive integer n.

It's Artinian since it's two dimensional over $F$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. $R$ has d.c.c. as an $F$-vector space. But, why does it have d.c.c. as a ring?

Comment: @karparvar every chain of ideals is a chain of F subspaces! If you had a strictly decreasing chain of ideals, then...(?)

Answer (score 0):

A Noetherian ring $R$ is Artinian if and only if its Krull dimension is zero, which is the case for $F[x]/(x^2)$ since it is an $F$-vector space of finite dimension.